# JRuby: Nokogiri 1.6 Failing To Install & Bundler Attempting To Install Already Met Dependency

Tags: ruby, jruby, bundler, nokogiri, trinidad-gem

I am getting an error on jruby (linux) when installing the
"trinidad_diagnostics_extension" gem (though this question is not about trinidad).  A chain of dependencies is
generating the error:

1. "trinidad_diagnostics_extension" depends on "jruby-lint >= 0.3.0"
2. "jruby-lint >= 0.3.0" in turn depends on "nokogiri >= 1.5.0.beta.4"
3. Before attempting to install "trinidad_diagnostics_extension", the relevant
   part of my gem list looks like this:

> ```
> $gem list
> nokogiri (1.5.9 java)
> jruby-lint (0.4.1)
> ```

As you can see, the needed dependencies seem already to be met.  Nonetheless,
after adding `gem 'trinidad_diagnostics_extension'` to my Gemfile and then
running `jruby -S bundle install`, the bundler attempts to install `nokogiri
(1.6.0.rc1)`, and during this installation fails with the following error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

... bunch of omitted output here

nokogiri.c:42:18: fatal error: util.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [nokogiri.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/jg/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0.rc1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/jg/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0.rc1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

1. Why is bundler trying to install nokogiri when that dependency is already met?
2. How can I fix this?  Successfully installing nokogiri 1.6 or making the trinidad extension aware that 1.6 does not need to be installed would both be fine solutions.

In case it's relevant I have `JRUBY_OPTS=-Xcext.enabled=true`

### UPDATE

I was able to get it work by first installing the gem outside of bundler:

```
jruby -S gem install trinidad_diagnostics_extension
```

And then the bundle command worked fine, since it was already installed.  So I got it working by I am still confused by why I had to install it outside of bundler and why that would matter, and would like some insight if anyone has it.

Comment: Maybe when you're doing `gem list

Comment: "`1.5.9 java`" is an unusual version number. Maybe Bundler doesn't parse it right and therefore doesn't know it satisfies the specified dependency.

Answer (score 0):

1.6.0.pre1 does not exist for the Java platform, for uninteresting reasons. That said, you should only get prereleases if you specifically ask for them.